# NSString – static or inline? Is there any performance gains?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring

Is there any performance gain if I write

```
- (NSString *)helloStringWithName:(NSString *)name
    static NSString *formatString = @"Hello %@!";
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:formatString, name];
}
```

instead of

```
- (NSString *)helloStringWithName:(NSString *)name
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@!", name];
}
```

??

If I were to guess I would think that the latter one is created and autoreleased each time the code is running, but I guess the compiler is smart enough to know what do here..

Comment: I don't have a way to compile anything right at this moment, but an easy way to test this is to see what the assembly for each looks like and draw your own conclusions from that (they shouldn't be different in any notable way). Also, I'm reasonably sure that NSString literals are allocated once and never deallocated (during the lifetime of an application).

Comment: You can run a test, just add a loop around it and log the time taken...

Comment: +1. The compiler really should be clever enough for this, but the `static` pattern is all over Apple's documentation sample code.

Comment: For static string declared locally, the compiler must maintain a flag whether it was instantiated or not and check each time control is passed to the function. I would look at the assembly code to be able to ascertain which might be better

Comment: that would be better to use `– (NSString *)helloStringWithName:(...)` instead of the `void`.

Comment: If you are really after that nano seconds performance gain, you shouldn't even think about NSString, not even NSObject, not even Objective-C   ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper +1, I added a note about that in my answer

Comment: The one you think is faster (using static) will in fact be slower and use more RAM. Not very much slower and not very much RAM, but it will be measurable. Better to stick with the second case, since the compiler is designedto make this style of programming as fast as possible.

Comment: Also, when working on performance, you should always wait until you find something that is actually slow, and then find out why it's slow and fix that. Never try to make something "fast" until after you have proven that it is actually slow. Often when you make something faster without first proving that it was slow in the first place, you end up actually making it slower or introducing bugs.

Comment: @holex Thanks for spotting that typo

Comment: @AbhiBeckert I totally agree. It's sometimes just great to know the possibilities!

Comment: The top is (ever so slightly) worse, since it unnecessarily ties up a static location.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

String literals in Objective-C are allocated at compile time, therefore you won't reasonably gain anything in performance.

Considers this

```
NSString * str = @"Hello";    
NSString * str2 = @"Hello";

NSLog(@"%p", str);  // => 0x860358
NSLog(@"%p", str2); // => 0x860358
```

Therefore if your intent is to say something like:

"*Hey compiler, the format string is always the same so don't bother allocating that more than once*"

the answer would be:

"*How nice, tell me something I don't know*"

**NOTE**

If you are still skeptical you can take a look at the assembly (check out Dirk's answer), but let me give you a piece of advice here: don't bang your head against such performance issues.

The overhead of using `NSString` and a high level abstraction as objects in general is definitely predominant in your program performances, so even if you gain a nanosecond per string, you won't reasonably even notice that.
And as you rightfully suspect, the compiler is already smart enough to take care of such details.

To wrap it up: let the compiler do its job and you do yours, i.e. writing readable and maintainable code.

Answer (score 14):

If you try this out (Menu->Product->Generate Output->Assembly File) - you'll note virtually identical output under clang - with only small changes due to the extra variable assignment & debugging info left.

So in short - no real difference; though the static one may be a bit easier to debug I guess.

```
    .align  4, 0x90
"-[Foo helloStringWithName1:]":         ## @"\01-[Foo helloStringWithName1:]"
    .cfi_startproc
Lfunc_begin0:
    .loc    1 15 0                  ## /Users/dirkx/tmp/ccccc/ccccc/main.m:15:0
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $48, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, %rdi
    callq   _objc_retain
    movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)
    .loc    1 17 5 prologue_end     ## /Users/dirkx/tmp/ccccc/ccccc/main.m:17:5
Ltmp5:
    movq    L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_(%rip), %rax
    movq    "-[Foo helloStringWithName1:].formatString"(%rip), %rdx
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_(%rip), %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   _objc_msgSend
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   _objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue
    movabsq $0, %rsi
    leaq    -24(%rbp), %rcx
    movl    $1, -28(%rbp)
    .loc    1 18 1                  ## /Users/dirkx/tmp/ccccc/ccccc/main.m:18:1
    movq    %rcx, %rdi
    movq    %rax, -40(%rbp)         ## 8-byte Spill
    callq   _objc_storeStrong
Ltmp6:
    .loc    1 18 1                  ## /Users/dirkx/tmp/ccccc/ccccc/main.m:18:1
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rax         ## 8-byte Reload
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   _objc_autoreleaseReturnValue
    .loc    1 17 5                  ## /Users/dirkx/tmp/ccccc/ccccc/main.m:17:5
Ltmp7:
    addq    $48, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
Ltmp8:
Lfunc_end0:
    .cfi_endproc
```

versus

```
    .align  4, 0x90
"-[Foo helloStringWithName2:]":         ## @"\01-[Foo helloStringWithName2:]"
    .cfi_startproc
Lfunc_begin1:
    .loc    1 20 0                  ## /Users/dirkx/tmp/ccccc/ccccc/main.m:20:0
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp11:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp12:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp13:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $48, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, %rdi
    callq   _objc_retain
    leaq    L__unnamed_cfstring_2(%rip), %rdx  <-------------------- 
    movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)
    .loc    1 21 5 prologue_end     ## /Users/dirkx/tmp/ccccc/ccccc/main.m:21:5
Ltmp14:
    movq    L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_(%rip), %rax
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_(%rip), %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   _objc_msgSend
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   _objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue
    movabsq $0, %rsi
    leaq    -24(%rbp), %rcx
    movl    $1, -28(%rbp)
    .loc    1 22 1                  ## /Users/dirkx/tmp/ccccc/ccccc/main.m:22:1
    movq    %rcx, %rdi
    movq    %rax, -40(%rbp)         ## 8-byte Spill
    callq   _objc_storeStrong
Ltmp15:
    .loc    1 22 1                  ## /Users/dirkx/tmp/ccccc/ccccc/main.m:22:1
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rax         ## 8-byte Reload
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   _objc_autoreleaseReturnValue
    .loc    1 21 5                  ## /Users/dirkx/tmp/ccccc/ccccc/main.m:21:5
Ltmp16:
    addq    $48, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
Ltmp17:
Lfunc_end1:
    .cfi_endproc
```

with as key references:

```
Lfunc_end2:
    .cfi_endproc

    .section    __DATA,__data
    .align  3                       ## @"\01-[Foo helloStringWithName1:].formatString"
"-[Foo helloStringWithName1:].formatString":
    .quad   L__unnamed_cfstring_

    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
l_.str:                                 ## @.str
    .asciz   "Hello 1 %@!"
```

and

```
    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
l_.str1:                                ## @.str1
    .asciz   "Hello 2 %@!"
```