# Will dispatch_once help on a simple NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, grand-central-dispatch

dispatch_once

```
+ (NSArray *)titles
{
    static NSArray *_titles;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _titles = @[@"Your Move",
                    @"Their Move",
                    @"Won Games",
                    @"Lost Games",
                    @"Options"];
    });
    return _titles;
}
```

Simple

```
+ (NSArray *)titles
{
     return @[@"Your Move",
              @"Their Move",
              @"Won Games",
              @"Lost Games",
              @"Options"];
}
```

Which is fastest? Isn't the compiler pretty smart? With strings we have no performance gain wrapping them in dispatch_once ([NSString – static or inline? Is there any performance gains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250064/nsstring-static-or-inline-is-there-any-performance-gains)). So it all boils down to wether this array is allocated each time or not, right?

Comment: I'd say for this, performance differences are so small, they may as well be considered the same. I the difference here is allocating and instantiating the array once vs. multiple times

Comment: The former is definitely faster, but it won't be observable except in the most extreme situations (i.e. calling it millions of times). In those degenerate situations, the issue is not simply the inefficiency of allocating a new array each time, but also that this is an autorelease object and so you need to make sure the pool is drained with regularity. But neither the performance nor memory concern will be observable in typical use of `titles`.

Comment: And in case you're thinking "if it's even marginally faster, why not?", I'll point out that 1) it's more code, 2) it makes the code harder to read, and 3) it takes time to write it. Over a long enough timeline, premature optimizations like this can really add up. A wise man once told me: "Make it work. Make it work right. Make it fast. (In that order.)" In terms of performance, don't try to improve what you haven't measured. Once you've measured, tackle the biggest problems first. Don't chase down micro-optimizations like this until there's *nothing* else left and perf is still unacceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is, how often this code will be executed. If it was several thousand times per second it might would matter, as it would save few millisecond on each run. But from the titles I would expect it will be accessed occasionally, maybe every 10 min. If you compare few milliseconds with 600 seconds you get a very small, nearly inexistent, improvement.

This would be micro optimisation.

Instead you should optimise under 2 condition: During runtime you see a need to optimise and you are able to identify a code block that would give you a huge improvement if it would be optimised. To find these use Instruments.

Answer (score 0):

The dispatch_once method is faster. A little bit on every call, plus the fact that without dispatch_once every call creates an array which is later deallocated, which might lead to memory pressure in a tight loop.

On the other hand, dispatch_once is more code.

If you plan to call the method gazillions of times, use dispatch_once. Otherwise don't bother, unless you have a different situation where you don't just create an array but do something a lot more expensive.